# Proper require unit test

Tags: php, oop, testing, phpunit

I have been writing a unit test for an app and wanted to test a method which has `require`. The way I see it

```
public $configPath = __DIR__.'/path/to/config.php';

private function getConfig()
{
    if (!empty($this->config)) {
        return $this->config;
    }

    return $this->config = require $this->configPath;
}

public method foo()
{
    $config = $this->getConfig(); 
    //logic here
}
```

In the test case, the respective snippet is

```
$class->config = ['bar' => 'baz'];

$class->foo();
```

I am wondering if this could be considered as the proper way or other technique/solution should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `require` statement loads a file from the filesystem. Since it interacts with the infrastructure it should be integration tested rather than unit tested. However, there are ways of decoupling from the filesystem so you could properly unit test it.

**Integration test**

If you decided to write an integration test for your class, you could make the path to the configuration file configurable via a constructor argument. This way you'll be able to pass a "test" config file with values you can rely on in the test.

**Unit test**

If you decided to write a unit test you'd need to move file loading out of your class. Either pass result of loading the config file as a constructor argument, or delegate file loading to a collaborator (i.e. `ConfigLoader`). You'll be able to stub the `ConfigLoader` in your unit test. The implementation of `ConfigLoader` will be very simple and you'll write an integration test for it (just to see if file is loaded and array is returned).

For example:

```php
class ConfigLoader
{
    public function load($file)
    {
        $config = require $file;

        if (!is_array($config)) {
            throw new InvalidConfigFileException(sprintf('Did not find configuration in "%s".', $file));
        }

        return $config;
    }
}
```

**Which approach to choose?**

It depends on what's the responsibility of the config class you're trying to test (remember of Single Responsibility Principle).

If the responsibility of the config class is related purely to loading a config file - integration test it. If there's something more to it - extract the file loading responsibility to its own class.

Comment: so because of `integration` testing, do you suppose that it should be left as is? I mean, what if user doesn't provide a particular `key/value/whatever´ and the app crashes?

Comment: In your opinion, should I go with the integration approach? :)

Comment: Depends how much logic there is in your config class - what's the responsibility of this class? If it's purely for loading a file - integration test it. If there's something more to it - extract loading responsibility to its own class.